# Getting column heading class from JSON array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a JSON from which I'm building a dynamic table. The JSON is as below:

```
var StatJSON = {
        "Option1": {
            "ColHeading": "Volvo",
            "Height": "aaa cm",
            "Weight": "xxx kg",
        },
        "Option2": {
            "ColHeading": "Mercedes",
            "Height": "bbb cm",
            "Weight": "yyy kg",
        },
        "Option3": {
            "ColHeading": "Maruti",
            "Height": "ccc cm",
            "Weight": "zzz kg",
        },
    };
```

What I need is a jQuery function that will allow me to get 'Option1', 'Option2' and 'Option3' (The heading of each array) as the class for the column headings for the respective columns in the table. Is this possible??

Below is the code I'm using for building the table:

```
function PrintTable(data) {
  var html = '<table class="compTable"><thead><tr><th>';
  if (data && data.length) {
    html += '</th>';
    jQuery.each(data, function(i) {
      html += '<th">' + StatJSON[data[i]].ColHeading + '</th>';
    });
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '<tbody>';
    jQuery.each(StatJSON[data[0]], function(k, v) {
        html += '<tr>';
            if (k != "ColHeading") {
        html += '<td>' + k + '</td>';
            }
        jQuery.each(data, function(k2, v2) {
            if (k != "ColHeading") {
        html += '<td>' + StatJSON[data[k2]][k] + '</td>';
            }
      });
      html += '</tr>';
    });
  } else { html += 'No results found</td></tr>'; }
  html += '</tbody></table>';
  return html;
}
```

Below is the entire working code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  var StatJSON = {
    "Option1": {
      "ColHeading": "Volvo",
      "Height": "aaa cm",
      "Weight": "xxx kg",
    },
    "Option2": {
      "ColHeading": "Mercedes",
      "Height": "bbb cm",
      "Weight": "yyy kg",
    },
    "Option3": {
      "ColHeading": "Maruti",
      "Height": "ccc cm",
      "Weight": "zzz kg",
    },
  };

  jQuery('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var data = [];
    jQuery("#selection").find(':selected').each(function(e) {
      var this_input = jQuery(this);
      if (this_input.is(':selected')) {
        data.push(this_input.val());
      }
    });

    $('#divResult').empty().append(PrintTable(data));

    function PrintTable(data) {
      var html = '<table class="compTable"><thead><tr><th>';
      if (data && data.length) {
        html += '</th>';
        jQuery.each(data, function(i) {
          html += '<th>' + StatJSON[data[i]].ColHeading + '</th>';
        });
        html += '</tr>';
        html += '<tbody>';
        jQuery.each(StatJSON[data[0]], function(k, v) {
          html += '<tr>';
          if (k != "ColHeading") {
            html += '<td>' + k + '</td>';
          }
          jQuery.each(data, function(k2, v2) {
            if (k != "ColHeading") {
              html += '<td>' + StatJSON[data[k2]][k] + '</td>';
            }
          });
          html += '</tr>';
        });
      } else {
        html += 'No results found</td></tr>';
      }
      html += '</tbody></table>';
      return html;
    }

  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: montserratbold, montserratregular, sans-serif;
}

.divResult {
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.compTable {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="selection" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="Option1">Volvo</option>
  <option value="Option2">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="Option3">Maruti</option>
  <br />
  <input id="btnSubmit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit" />
</select>
<br /><br />
<div id="divResult" class="divResult"></div>
```

Comment: You need add `<th class="option1"`..etc ? If yes you already have that value inside `data` simply use `html += '<th class='+data[i]+'>' + StatJSON[..`

Comment: Hi @Swati! Just curious, but how would you add this class as a seperate jquery command. I tried using `jQuery('.divResult table thead th:not(:first)').each(function () {jQuery(this).addClass(StatJSON[data[i]]);});` but this doesnt work as 'i' is not defined outside the "function PrintTable(data)". How can I do this with a seperate jquery command outside the function used to build the table?

Comment: Like this `jQuery('.divResult table thead th:not(:first)').each(function(i) { jQuery(this).addClass(data[i]);});` Here , `data` will be array as in your code you have with selected option .